# using javascript in html to display current date

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have this script which display Gregorian-Hijri date:

```js
var fixd = document.getElementById('date');

function isGregLeapYear(year) {
  return year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0;
}

function gregToFixed(year, month, day) {
  var a = Math.floor((year - 1) / 4);
  var b = Math.floor((year - 1) / 100);
  var c = Math.floor((year - 1) / 400);
  var d = Math.floor((367 * month - 362) / 12);
  if (month <= 2)
    e = 0;
  else if (month > 2 && isGregLeapYear(year))
    e = -1;
  else
    e = -2;
  return 1 - 1 + 365 * (year - 1) + a - b + c + d + e + day;
}

function Hijri(year, month, day) {
  this.year = year;
  this.month = month;
  this.day = day;
  this.toFixed = hijriToFixed;
  this.toString = hijriToString;
}

function hijriToFixed() {
  return this.day + Math.ceil(29.5 * (this.month - 1)) + (this.year - 1) * 354 +
    Math.floor((3 + 11 * this.year) / 30) + 227015 - 1;
}

function hijriToString() {
  var months = new Array("محرم", "صفر", "ربيع الأول", "ربيع الثانى", "جمادى الأولى", "جمادى الثانية", "رجب", "شعبان", "رمضان", "شوال", "ذو القعدة", "ذو الحجة");
  return this.day + " " + months[this.month - 1] + " " + this.year;
}

function fixedToHijri(f) {
  var i = new Hijri(1100, 1, 1);
  i.year = Math.floor((30 * (f - 227015) + 10646) / 10631);
  var i2 = new Hijri(i.year, 1, 1);
  var m = Math.ceil((f - 29 - i2.toFixed()) / 29.5) + 1;
  i.month = Math.min(m, 12);
  i2.year = i.year;
  i2.month = i.month;
  i2.day = 1;
  i.day = f - i2.toFixed() + 1;
  return i;
}
var tod = new Date();
var weekday = new Array("الأحد", "الإثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت");
var monthname = new Array("يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "ابريل", "ماي", "جوان", "جويلية", "أوت", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر");
var y = tod.getFullYear();
var m = tod.getMonth();
var d = tod.getDate();
var dow = tod.getDay();
document.write(weekday[dow] + " " + d + " " + monthname[m] + " " + y);
m++;
fixd = gregToFixed(y, m, d);
var h = new Hijri(1421, 11, 28);
h = fixedToHijri(fixd);
document.write("  / " + h.toString() + "   ");
```

```html
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li id="date"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use it in `<li>` tag

and if it is possible to display the date in two different positions at the same time at the same page

actually I am not familiar with java script so I don't know how to modify this script and then call it by id or whatever in html tag

any help please

Comment: You can't use the same ID multiple times in the same document. You could use a class or an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set something like an attribute to any element that needs the date and then assign the innerHTML of that element.

This is all your code except I moved the 'loose' parts into a function that returns the finished date. Then this line

```
document.querySelectorAll('[display-date]')
  .forEach(el => el.innerHTML = getTheDate())
```

says *find all elements with the attribute display-date and insert the results of the date function in them*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[display-date]').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = getTheDate())
})

function isGregLeapYear(year) {
  return year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0;
}

function gregToFixed(year, month, day) {
  var a = Math.floor((year - 1) / 4);
  var b = Math.floor((year - 1) / 100);
  var c = Math.floor((year - 1) / 400);
  var d = Math.floor((367 * month - 362) / 12);
  if (month <= 2)
    e = 0;
  else if (month > 2 && isGregLeapYear(year))
    e = -1;
  else
    e = -2;
  return 1 - 1 + 365 * (year - 1) + a - b + c + d + e + day;
}

function Hijri(year, month, day) {
  this.year = year;
  this.month = month;
  this.day = day;
  this.toFixed = hijriToFixed;
  this.toString = hijriToString;
}

function hijriToFixed() {
  return this.day + Math.ceil(29.5 * (this.month - 1)) + (this.year - 1) * 354 +
    Math.floor((3 + 11 * this.year) / 30) + 227015 - 1;
}

function hijriToString() {
  var months = new Array("محرم", "صفر", "ربيع الأول", "ربيع الثانى", "جمادى الأولى", "جمادى الثانية", "رجب", "شعبان", "رمضان", "شوال", "ذو القعدة", "ذو الحجة");
  return this.day + " " + months[this.month - 1] + " " + this.year;
}

function fixedToHijri(f) {
  var i = new Hijri(1100, 1, 1);
  i.year = Math.floor((30 * (f - 227015) + 10646) / 10631);
  var i2 = new Hijri(i.year, 1, 1);
  var m = Math.ceil((f - 29 - i2.toFixed()) / 29.5) + 1;
  i.month = Math.min(m, 12);
  i2.year = i.year;
  i2.month = i.month;
  i2.day = 1;
  i.day = f - i2.toFixed() + 1;
  return i;
}

function getTheDate() {

  var tod = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array("الأحد", "الإثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت");
  var monthname = new Array("يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "ابريل", "ماي", "جوان", "جويلية", "أوت", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر");
  var y = tod.getFullYear();
  var m = tod.getMonth();
  var d = tod.getDate();
  var dow = tod.getDay();
  let d1 = (weekday[dow] + " " + d + " " + monthname[m] + " " + y);
  m++;
  fixd = gregToFixed(y, m, d);
  var h = new Hijri(1421, 11, 28);
  h = fixedToHijri(fixd);
  let d2 = "  / " + h.toString() + "   ";
  return d1 + d2;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li display-date class="date"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h3 display-date></h3>
<p>Todays date is <span display-date></span></p>
```

Comment: thanks alot .. it works well but show me only Gregorian date .. i want both Gregorian and Hijri date

Comment: @TahaniAl-abri ok. together? one on top of the other? or side by side? or do you want to be able to decide which on a per-element basis?

Comment: side by side please

Answer (score 1):

This is really an extended comment.

The code can be considerably reduced by using the *ca* option with either [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) to set the calendar for formatted dates. It can also be used to set the language, e.g.

```js
let d = new Date();
let options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'long'
};
console.log(
  'Gregorian English: ' + d.toLocaleString('en-u-ca-gergory', options) + '\n' +
  'Hijri English    : ' + d.toLocaleString('en-u-ca-islamic', options) + '\n' +
  'Hijri Arabic     : ' + d.toLocaleString('ar-u-ca-islamic', options)
);
```

You can also use the [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) method to get the various parts and order or format them any way you wish.

Comment: This is a simple method indeed. It is all in there in Javascript.

Comment: Voting your answer up. 